# Podio Calendar, how to get the calendar of a particular user

Tags: php, events, calendar, podio

How can I get the calendar of a particular user?

Im working on a Podio-to-calendar implementation and want to do that, but so far, I had no positive results.

I can get all the events for workspace, app, etc using the examples and documentation in https://developers.podio.com/doc/calendar .

- Is there any calendar method to get the data for a user across Podio?
- In that case, can I get even the data that has been synced from another calendar, like the one in my google account? I have the feeling that those events are not saved as podio items at all, am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For getting global calendar I'd start with https://developers.podio.com/doc/calendar/get-global-calendar-22458 method.
2. For linked account's calendars, you are right - Podio doesn't import event from them as items, they are only displayed on calendar. To get those you should use: https://developers.podio.com/doc/calendar/get-linked-account-calendar-78081299. And to get linked account, you will need this one: https://developers.podio.com/doc/linked-accounts